# IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_DOUBLE warning: Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

During the course of a problem I'm working on Pig, I generated a transition file the records of which looks like this:

```
(0131228,-1.9,12.8)
(0131229,12.8,30.4)
(0131230,20.6,32.3)
(0131231,21.0,32.4)
```

I've typecasted the middle(Max_Temp) and end(Min_Temp) values to double.

```
B1 = LOAD '/tmp/PigLoadSandstoneData/part-m-00000' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Dated: CHARARRAY, Min_Temp: DOUBLE, Max_Temp: DOUBLE);
```

I wanted to filter out the result as per a comparison that I'm doing using the statements below:

```
X = filter B1 by Max_Temp>25.0;
X = filter B1 by Min_Temp<0.0;
```

I'm not sure why it is throwing the IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_DOUBLE error message as:

```
grunt> X = filter B1 by (Max_Temp>25.0);
2014-04-08 05:42:58,925 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_DOUBLE 1 time(s).
```

Can anyone please suggest what wrong I'm doing here? And any solution to this?

Thanks-
Adil

Comment: What version of Pig are you on? Your example doesn't produce the warning for me. Also, I think you have your `Max_Temp` and `Min_Temp` fields swapped in your example `LOAD` function.

Comment: @andrewjd: The version is 0.11 Andrew. And yes, by looking at the values it appears the obvious but the dataset I've gotten is like that only. But anyhow, I swapped the values and tried the same logic but the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give these a shot and tell me if one or neither works:

1. I'd try tossing in a cast in the `FILTER` statement, e.g.,

   `X = filter B1 by (double)Max_Temp>25.0;`
2. It's not impossible that you have a null value somewhere in your data set that Pig is re-casting. Try filtering out null values. If you want to do something with the null value (e.g., set it to 0) try [COALESCE](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/util/Coalesce.html).

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions Andrew. But before posting this question here, I tried everything. The typecasting on either side, both sides, everything. Even I tried loading the file in float and not double. But then again, it has the similar issue. Also, there are no null values; I already had that checked. After I couldn't get anything my hands on, I tried asking here :)

Comment: Honestly, since it's a warning (not an error) and an upcast (as opposed to a downcast, like from the double `5.4` to the int `5`), I wouldn't let it concern you terribly much. If all your inputs are numbers, the worst you could be doing is casting a null value to a zero. Also, if your inputs weren't numbers, you would've received a different error message.

Comment: you've a point. 
Let me try some workarounds. Thanks for suggestions Andrew, appreciate it.

Comment: Got that resolved. I think there was some issue with the terminal I was in or some temp file issue, not sure. Had the terminal exit, removed the files created and did a fresh start. All steps went well. Still not sure what could have caused the problem. Thanks for the suggestions.